# Django with Oracle DB - ORA-19011: Character string buffer too small

Tags: python, django, oracle

I have the following model for an Oracle database, which is not a part of my Django project:

```
class ResultsData(models.Model):
    RESULT_DATA_ID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column="RESULT_DATA_ID")
    RESULT_XML = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, db_column="RESULT_XML")
    
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = '"schema_name"."results_data"'
```

The RESULT_XML field in the database itself is declared as XMLField. I chose to represent it as TextField in Django model, due to no character limit.
When I do try to download some data with that model, I get the following error:

```
DatabaseError: ORA-19011: Character string buffer too small
```

I figure, it is because of the volume of data stored in RESULT_XML field, since when I try to just pull a record with .values("RESULT_DATA_ID"), it pulls fine.

Any ideas on how I can work around this problem? Googling for answers did not yield anything so far.

Comment: Sadly the XML team never gave good client support through the Oracle C stack (luckily JSON support is much better!) Typically there are length issues.  Can you create a view on the table like `SELECT XMLTYPE.GETCLOBVAL(mycol) FROM mytab` and query that?  This is a "standard" solution: https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/xml_data_type.html. You might also need to tell cx_Oracle to fetch LOBs as strings, see the output type handler in https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/main/samples/return_lobs_as_strings.py

Comment: I see you opened https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68914827/django-custom-getter-for-1-field-in-model

Comment: Yes, based on your response I have actually worked out a solution which gave me what I wanted, but with use of a raw SQL query, which kind of does not satisfy uniformity of using Django ORM as much as possible. I`ll post the answer to my own question shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER**
I have found a much better way of dealing with that issue - I wrote a custom field value Transform object, which generates an Oracle SQL query I was after:

*OracleTransforms.py*

```
from django.db.models import TextField
from django.db.models.lookups import Transform


class CLOBVAL(Transform):
    '''
    Oracle-specific transform for XMLType field, which returns string data exceeding 
    buffer size (ORA-19011: Character string buffer too small) as a character LOB type.
    '''
    function = None
    lookup_name = 'clobval'

    def as_oracle(self, compiler, connection, **extra_context):
        return super().as_sql(
            compiler, connection,
            template='(%(expressions)s).GETCLOBVAL()',
            **extra_context
        )

# Needed for CLOBVAL to work as a .values('field_name__clobval') lookup in Django ORM queries
TextField.register_lookup(CLOBVAL)
```

With the above, I can now just write a query as follows:

```
from .OracleTransforms import CLOBVAL

ResultsData.objects.filter(RESULT_DATA_ID=some_id).values('RESULT_DATA_ID', 'RESULT_XML__clobval')

or

ResultsData.objects.filter(RESULT_DATA_ID=some_id).values('RESULT_DATA_ID', XML = CLOBVAL('RESULT_XML'))
```

This is the best solution for me, as I do get to keep using QuerySet, instead of RawQuerySet.
The only limitation I see with this solution for now, is that I need to always specify .values(CLOBVAL('RESULT_XML')) in my ORM queries, or Oracle DB will report ORA-19011 again, but I guess this still is a good outcome.

**OLD ANSWER**
So, I have found a way around the problem, thanks to Christopher Jones suggestion.

ORA-19011 is an error which Oracle DB replies with, when the amount of data it would be sending back as a string exceeds allowed buffer. Therefore, it needs to be sent back as a character LOB object instead.

Django does not have a direct support for that Oracle-specific method (at least I did not find one), so an answer to the problem was a raw Django query:

```
query = 'select a.RESULT_DATA_ID, a.RESULT_XML.getClobVal() as RESULT_XML FROM SCHEMA_NAME.RESULTS_DATA a WHERE a.RESULT_DATA_ID=%s'

data = ResultsData.objects.raw(query, [id])
```

This way, you get back a RawQuerySet, which if this less known, less liked cousin of Django's QuerySet. You can iterate through the answer, and RESULT_XML  will contain a LOB field, which when interrogated will convert to a String type.

Handling a String type-encoded XML data is problematic, so I also employed XMLTODICT Python package, to get it into a bit more civilized shape.

Next, I should probably look for a way to modify Django's getter for the RESULT_XML field only, and have it generate a query to Oracle DB with .getClobVal() method in it, but I will touch on that in a different StackOverflow question: [Django - custom getter for 1 field in model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68914827/django-custom-getter-for-1-field-in-model)

Comment: Can't you create a view, and get Django to use the view?

Comment: Would love to, but this is a call to an external DB, outside of my influence. Access privileges I was given do not allow me to create views, as far as I can tell.