# Django - custom getter for 1 field in model

Tags: python, django, oracle

I am writing a model for an external Oracle DB, which I need to pull info from to my project. One of the fields in that Oracle DB is an XMLType, and it hosts large portion of data, which needs to be pulled via .getClobVal() method, instead of querying it straight as it is.

I was wondering, if Django supports any sort of custom logic, for Model's specific fields. Something along the lines of a getter for each field, which I could overwrite to query that specific field as XMLType.getClobVal() instead of just XMLType. At the same time, I don`t want to touch the logic for querying the rest of the Model's fields.

Any ideas?